# { [Error: SIGNATURE_INVALID] code: 'auth/invalid-custom-token', message: 'SIGNATURE_INVALID' }

Tags: nodejs, firebase

Estoy intentando iniciar sesión en Firebase con un token personalizado. He seguido todos los pasos y el token decodificado sería así, siguiendo todos los requisitos de Google:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

{
  "id": 397,
  "uid": "397",
  "email": "my@example.com",
  "permission": null,
  "iss": "firebase-adminsdk-a6ppo@ziimapp-202314.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub": "firebase-adminsdk-a6ppo@ziimapp-202314.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "aud": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
  "type_user": "user",
  "iat": 1545044517,
  "exp": 1545048117
}
```

Tras estar peleándome con el JWT he llegado a un punto en el que consigo este error:

```
{ [Error: SIGNATURE_INVALID]
  code: 'auth/invalid-custom-token',
  message: 'SIGNATURE_INVALID' }
```

Y la clave la estoy pasando de esta forma:

```
let token = jwt.sign(payload, keyData.private_key, { expiresIn: '3600s', algorithm: 'RS256' })
```

La clave tiene el siguiente formato:

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 mi Llave Privada
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```